# Problema con la Fecha en MSSQL en una página ASP.NET 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un problema al querer ingresar la fecha a una tabla en SQL pues el día de ayer me funcionaba correctamente, pero al tratar de ejecutar la página me salio este error:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [22007] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Me dice que en la línea 181:

```
Línea 179:            OdbcCommand cmda = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM SVenta B INNER JOIN Vendedores A ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = '" + Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]) + "' AND B.Fecha = '"+Label4.Text + "'", cn);
Línea 180:            OdbcDataAdapter daa = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmda);
Línea 181:            daa.Fill(dta);
Línea 182:            GRILLA.DataSourceID = null;
Línea 183:            GRILLA.DataSource = dta;`
```

Y cuando intento ejecutar en un query de sql:

```
SELECT convert(date, '13/06/2018', 101)
```

Me saca el mismo error, aún si intento desde ahí ingresar los datos a la tabla. El error dice así:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Ya busqué en otros foros alguna respuesta pero tienen que ver con otras causas y las respuestas no me han funcionado, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Mira, el formato que ocupo para mostrar la fecha en `Label4.Text` es dd/MM/yyyy y por eso a la hora de insertar o consultar lo convierto, te comento que ayer me funcionaba bien y hoy no se qué pasó. Y si quito la conversión sigue igual

Comment: ¿Cambios en la configuración regional del equipo?

Comment: A ver. Entiendo que `Fecha` es una columna `DateTime`? Si es así, por qué le pasas la fecha a buscar como un String? Y por qué no usas una consulta parametrizada y probablemente asi no tendrías este problema? :)

Comment: Y otra cosa. Si es sql-server, por que usas odbc en lugar del conector nativo para Sql Server?

Comment: @Pikoh Utilizo Odbc para generar la Conección con SQL, pues esta en un equipo remoto y directamente no me permite conectar. Además son cuestiones de la empresa.

Comment: @Elizabeth si son cuestiones de empresa, no hay nada mas que hablar, la empresa manda :). De todas maneras, que el equipo sea remoto obviamente no es excusa, normalmente los servidores suelen ser equipos remotos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema y otros muchos mas (sobre todo y principalmente, la [**Inyeccion SQL**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)), se solucionan usando **siempre** consultas parametrizadas. El problema es que en tu consulta estas pasando un string con la fecha cuando en realidad lo que tienes que hacer es pasar la fecha en si.

Veamos como sería:

```
OdbcCommand cmda = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM SVenta B INNER JOIN Vendedores A ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = ? AND B.Fecha = ?", cn);
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]));
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha", DateTime.Parse(Label4.Text));
daa.Fill(dta);
```

En este caso, al usar odbc los parametros no tienen nombre.

Te recomiendo de todas maneras, si estas usando SqlServer, que utilices el conector nativo de SqlServer en lugar de odbc.

Answer (score 1):

El formato buscado de convert es:

```
SELECT convert(date, '13/06/2018', 103)
```

El cual es `British/French` acepta el formato de fecha `dd/mm/yyyy` quedando tu comando:

```
OdbcCommand cmda = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM SVenta B INNER JOIN Vendedores A ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = '" + Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]) + "' AND B.Fecha =  convert(date, '"+Label4.Text + "', 103)", cn);
```

> Nota: Los comentarios hechos por Pikoh a tu publicacion dan un mejor enfoque para
>   evitar este problema a futuro

Comment: Gracias, lo pude resolver así, pero aún quisiera que me explicaras por qué surgió el error, pues como comento veces anteriores lo utilicé con 101 y funcionaba bien.

Comment: Ojo con 101 ya que el formato es mm/dd/yyyy por lo que la fecha 1/3/2018 seria Enero 3 del 2018 en lugar de 1 de Marzo de 2018 que seria con la 103, este es un enlace de los formatos aceptados y devueltos por ms sql server: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp